# Calculating current with given voltage and load

Tags: dc-motor

[image]

Graph 1: Voltage [V]
Graph 2 (green): angular speed [rad/s]
Graph 3 (blue): Current [A]
Graph 4: load moment [Nm]

I've got a DC-motor with the following constants:
$$R = 365\cdot 10^{-3}\Omega$$
$$k_e = 0.1227Vs$$
$$k_m = 0.123Nm/A$$
$$C_r = 92.4929\cdot 10^{-6}Nm\cdot s$$
$$L = 161nH$$
$$J = 134\cdot 10^{-6}kg\cdot m^2$$

I want to calculate the current at the given test points 1 to 5. 2, 4 and 5 are no problem but 1 and 3 are difficult since we have to consider the inductance.

My approach is:

$$U(t) = R\cdot i + L \frac{di(t)}{dt}$$

If I could ignore the inductance, I would just say
$$ I = \frac{U}{R} $$
How to consider the inductance correctly?
Is it even possible to do it correctly with the given data?

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: ”Moment” is a false friend between English and Germanic languages. You mean torque.

Comment: From stall condition with 48 volts applied and a rotor resistance of 0.365 ohms, I would expect to see more like 132 amps at point 1 rather than 2.5 amps unless, of course the invisible y axis on current is 50 amps per division then, it looks about right.